# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 doesn't build when path to project long

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, msbuild, vdproj

I have solution with *.vdproj and use Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

When path to solution long `d:/so/long/path/for/my/solution/my_project/trunk/` visual studio fails on building, but I don't find any errors in error log or output:

```
========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I build project withour *.vdproj from msbuild - build complete without errors.

When I copy solution to short paht `d:/my_proj/` and build from visual studio - build complete without errors.

Problem reproduced in Win Xp x32 and Win 2008 R2 x64 and my project writen on c# 4.0. And I can't build solution from msbuild becouse I use *.vdproj project.

I can't change path to project. How I can fix my problem?

Comment: Looks like you're running into the 260 Win32 API char path limit

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running into the 260 Win32 API char path limit.

You could use the `subst` command to map part of the path to a drive letter. And then open the solution through that shorter path.

```
subst f: d:\so\long\path\for\my\solution\my_project
```

Now you can open your project as

```
f:\trunk
```

You could also use symlinks to shorten the bath in a similar way on vista and later.